# C++ CLI - ссылка на неразрешенную лексему

Tags: c++, реестр, clr

Данный код не выполняется в проекте:

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, sizeof(szPath));

HKEY hg;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hg);
RegSetValueEx(hg, L"KeyMe", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, 1024);
RegCloseKey(hg);
```

У функций работы с регистром возникают ошибки LNK2028, ссылка на неразрешенную лексему. Почитав о ней, я понял, что нужно правильно подключить библиотеку через `pragma`, но это касается lib библиотек, а работа с регистром описана в `windows.h` - заголовочный файл, как его подключить через `pragma`?

Comment: Раз уж вы пишете на C++/CLI, то используйте классы из .NET-фреймворка. [Registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: Видя `TCHAR`, не могу не дать ссылку на архиполезный материал: [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) - сложно, но важно. Переходите на светлую сторону: на utf-8 и всё с ним связанное.

Comment: Зачем? Этоже С++ а не C#, если нужна функция винапи, то её следует звать напрямую.
Хедер содержит описания функций, его нельзя подрубить через прагму.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa а вот Advapi32.lib можно попробовать.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков - в заголовке темы C++ CLI, в тегах стоит clr. Если автор не напутал и действительно юзает дотнет, то использование его возможностей, вероятно, будет проще.

Comment: Повторю то, что пишу всегда: язык C++/CLI не предназначен для написания приложений. Он нужен для склейки управляемого (managed) и неуправляемого нативного (unmanaged native) кода. Например, приложение пишется на C#, а в нём нужно использовать библиотеку на C++. Или, наоборот, приложение на C++, а библиотека на C#. Следовательно, сперва необходимо освоить платформу .NET (C#) и какой-либо язык наподобие C, C++ и лишь потом может возникнуть необходимость в C++/CLI. PS: если вас в учебном заведении заставляют писать приложения на этом языке, то передайте им от меня, что они редиски.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Укажите это майкросовту. В C++ проще и правильнее вызывать винапи напрямую.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков - В C++ да, а в C++/CLI - нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В коде вполне чистый С++. Выши выпады против C++/CLI здесь не к месту. Вполне возможно, что автор и использует по назначению, пишет основную часть на чистом С++, а С++/CLI использует для взаимодействия с .NET. А на вопрос Никита Самоуков ответил правильно, нужно подключить Advapi32.lib

Comment: Ребят, что с вами не так? В заголовке и метках указан C++/CLI. В нормальном C++ нужно использовать WinAPI - это естественно, я с этим не спорю. Но тогда нужно удалить метку и исправить заголовок. В C++/CLI правильнее будет использовать класс .NET. Я не говорил, что код нужно **обязательно** переписать. Я лишь предложил альтернативу именно для этого языка. @MSDN.WhiteKnight

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не так то, что вы навязываете ложное деление на "Нормальный С++" и "C++/CLI", что не соответствует действительности. Все, что нормально использовать в С++, нормально и в C++/CLI, в том и суть языка. С чего тут правильнее классы .NET? Там и выделения динамической памяти будет больше, и код выглядеть будет не намного проще, особенно если нельзя сделать using namespace из-за конфликтов.

Comment: Все что я выполняю - задание для курсовой, должно быть выполнено в виде оконного приложения, поэтому стал делать на CLI. Благодаря Advapi32.lib приложение запустилось, спасибо всем за ответы.